# Tag synonym: auc -> roc?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, tag-synonyms

I believe [auc](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/auc) should be a synonym for [roc](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/roc).  [auc](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/auc) was created only for [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/12309).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree with mpiktas -- those are divergent things. AUC can be done for PR curve for instance and sometimes one can be interested in ROC curve only, not its area.

Of course we certainly should do some audit of those tags, because there is some chaos in that manner.

Comment: Sure thing - I was just trying to tidy up a few tags - I did the casual Wikipedia search as I'd only heard of auc as it relates to roc -- fine to leave it as is.

Answer (score 3):

I am not an expert, but from quick search on wikipedia I got an impression that though ROC and AUC are related concepts, but they are not synonyms. So I suggest leaving everything as it is. Maybe adding roc tag to the question would be more appropriate?